# What is mean of "DWORD64 Rip" in CONTEXT structer?

Tags: winapi, process

What exactly is the role of the "DWORD64 Rip" variable in this CONTEXT structure that holds processor-specific register data?

I looked at MSDN but they didn't explain it there.

CONTEXT structer in MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-context#see-also

Comment: DWORD64 is a type, it's a 64 bit unsigned integer. And RIP is the name of a register, the instruction pointer.

Comment: x86 processor registers follow some naming conventions that allow you to know the size based on the name.  Take accumulator A for example:  AL and AH: one byte each.  AX: two bytes, combination of AH:AL.  EAX: four bytes, of which AX is the lower two.  RAX: eight bytes, of which EAX is the lower four.  Similarly the instruction pointer is named IP, EIP, or RIP depending on its size (which in turn depends on whether your processor is in x86_64 long mode or not).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I see. RIP meaning Register Instruction Pointer. Thank you

Comment: No.  RIP is a size prefix R and IP meaning instruction pointer.  R does not mean "Register".